# I need help on how to change the domain name to IP address

Tags: domains, dns, ip-address

I am fairly new to web development. Need help to change the domain name to IP address. Could anyone explain the steps in great detail on how to do this.

Basically, I want my url to appear on google as IP address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx instead of www.domain.com.

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to do that? A domain is portable. You can move it from host to host. When you lose hosting, you typically lose your IP address. Using an IP address in search engines ties you to a specific host. It is usually desirable to use a domain name for SEO and branding.

Comment: Hhmmm... the domain / IP address in the screenshot is not your site I presume?

Comment: Yes, the screenshot is not my site. My domain is in adult niche and my government is blocking all of those niche. I want to do this because an IP domain "supposedly" cant be blocked by my government yet. I searched a bit and people say you can use VPS to do it but I dont know how to do it. Would anyone be kind enough to teach me?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is going to solve your problem, because:

- the government could react by banning the IP address as soon as they have identified your site
- even if you are the only one using that IP address right now, and your activities do not directly penalize other clients that share the same IP address, the webhost could ask you to take your business elsewhere, because an IP address that is blacklisted becomes less usable - it's the same problem with spammers: they cause their IP address ranges to be blacklisted and for this reason they are seldom welcome
- if the government in question has equipment sophisticated enough they may be using DPI which means they can **selectively filter** Internet access, based on URL or page contents, meaning: banning domain names is not the only thing they can do

Probably the best you can do is rotate domain names often (like torrent sites), or move to Tor perhaps, but only a minority of people visit Tor and it would not be surprising it is censored as well.

It's possible that the censorship is rudimentary, for example some countries block torrent sites at DNS level and ISPs simply redirect or block requests for banned domain names.
But many people use public DNS like Google's or OpenDNS and are thus able to easily bypass the censorship (without even realizing it).
Without knowing the country in question it's hard to comment further.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know it may or may not solve my problem but I just need to know how to do it. My government can censors adult niche and gambling sites (which is my niche) but currently, IP address domains seem to be safe. 

Even if I redirect my blocked sites, it will still showed as blocked to the viewer in my country.